# How do I upload a file to a varbinary(max) column in SQL Server 2008, using TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This must be possible because I believe I've done it before. Here's my query:

```
insert into exampleFiles Values(NEWID(), cast('c:\filename.zip' as varbinary(max))
```

Obviously that just inserts the text in between the quotes and not the file from that location.  There must be a simple tsql bit of language that I'm forgetting. Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Does this help?

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
CREATE TABLE myTable(FileName nvarchar(60),
  FileType nvarchar(60), Document varbinary(max))
GO

INSERT INTO myTable(FileName, FileType, field_varbinary)
   SELECT 'Text1.txt' AS FileName,
      '.txt' AS FileType,
      * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Text1.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document
GO
```

Taken from here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/513cbf8c-21a8-4bcc-a565-6eb06437a398

Comment: it should be mentioned that the column in the OpenRowSet functions has the name BulkColumn. So you could use document.BulkColumn instead the * in your query.

Comment: So how do I insert multiple files in a query?

Comment: @AndersLindén - One idea is to add a UNION ALL with another SELECT for the second file. E.g. copy the first SELECT for the Text1.txt file, add UNION ALL, then past the SELECT and change the filename to Text2.txt.  I haven't tested this so I can't say if it actually works.

Comment: I created some variables of type varbinary(max), populated each of them with file contents and did an insert.